# How can I resize an extended partition to the left without moving it?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Testdisk made an extended partition end outside of my hard disk, so I fixed it with fixparts.  Problem is, I had originally had a bit of space in the beginning of the extended partition.  Now it's gone, and GParted wants me to move (read: copy) the entire extended partition (about 500GB) to the left before resizing it by 50GB.

How can I resize an extended (container) partition without moving the whole thing?  I am not averse to any command-line utilities.  I am running 12.10 in RAM right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, never mind.  I used `cfdisk` to make a dummy logical partition (which extended the extended partition) and then used GParted to delete it (which left the extended partition as-is).  Wish there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A partition is defined by where it begins and its length. To "extend it to the left", you would have to change where it begins, which means you'd have to move it.

Comment: Problem is, when GParted wants to move it it wants to copy the entire contents and then resize by changing the end point.  I just want to change the start point, which I know is possible (I saw testdisk do it before my eyes!)

Comment: Sorry I didn't define this properly in my question; will edit.